# Why can't I descend into the network share I have permanently mounted?

Tags: permissions, mount, nautilus, samba, fstab

I followed the instructions for permanently mounting a samba share by adding it to my fstab per the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

The folder is mounted now, but I can't descend into any of its subdirectories. In nautilus, they have Xes over the folder icon and when clicked on, I'm getting

"This location could not be displayed. Sorry, could not display all the contents of "Shared directory" Error opening directory /media/share/Shared directory. Invalid Argument."

How can I descend into those directories?

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIYA1.jpg

My fstab entry looks like this:

```
//sample.com/SMBShare  /media/SMBShare  cifs  credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Comment: Please add an image!

Comment: Smells like an ownership/permissions problem, or "mounted now" isn't accurate. No way to tell